# Adding music to iPhone 4s

Tags: xubuntu, sync, music, iphone

What is the best way to sync my music I have downloaded online with my iPhone using Xubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to add music to the default music player on an iphone running iOS 7 due to compatibility problems. An alternative solution is to install a alternative iphone media player, I use Oplayer lite which allows you to add music and play music uploaded from my pc to my iphone via browser and wifi. For further details on iphone functionality have a look at the following website.

http://www.libimobiledevice.org

Answer (score 3):

i think you can mount your device via usb and then just enable usb debugging in your device and then you can surely enjoy it.

once you have enabled usb debugging you can play them via rhythmbox music player

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to get the Apple music app to work but have had luck with VLC. I tried Linux based programs and had no success with Banshee (crahsed), Amarok, Clementine or any other Linux media players.

*This process requiers the installation of the VLC app on your iPhone but beyond that no extra third party applications.*

1. Install VLC app on your iPhone or iPod
2. Mount the iPhone and access `Documents on iPhone`
3. Using Nautilus or any other file browser navigate to the directory "VLC" -> "Documents"
4. Then simply drag and drop your Albums to the "Documents" directory.
   *file transfer was slower than usual but it did the trick.*
5. Eject/Unmount your iPhone
6. On your iPhone open the VLC app and let the Media library update.

***Restart the iPhone if you are having crashing or buggy performance from the VLC app after uploading new music.***