# Can not connect my iPhone to Ubuntu

Tags: iphone

I am trying to plug my iPhone with iOS7 to my Ubuntu computer. I have installed everything that is necessary, however I get the following error when I run `sudo ifuse /mnt/myiphone`,

```
usbmuxd_get_device_list: error opening socket!
No device found, is it connected?
If it is make sure that your user has permissions to access the raw usb device.
If you're still having issues try unplugging the device and reconnecting it.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/487237/adding-music-to-iphone-4s/487240#487240

Comment: When you plugin in your iPhone does it show up on the launcher? (I am assuming you are running Unity.)

Comment: @Cammy_the_block No, there is no launcher (I am not using Unity).

Comment: Recently [KDE Connect](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/kde-connect/id1580245991) was added to Apple Store

Answer (score 2):

##### Solution

Restart usbmuxd by running:
`systemctl restart usbmuxd`

##### More info

I was also unable to connect an iPhone to Ubuntu (but in 2022, not 2014). This worked for me:

- I ran "sudo systemctl status usbmuxd" and it stated that it was running ("usbmuxd.service - Socket daemon for the usbmux protocol used by Apple devices")
- I stopped it by running "sudo systemctl restart usbmuxd"; that command took to long so I quit it by hitting ctrl+c, which I guess is AKA ^C
- I ran "sudo systemctl status usbmuxd" and it stated that it was "deactivating (stop-sigterm)"
- I then ran "sudo systemctl start usbmuxd" to reactivate usbmuxd.
- I was then able to access the iPhone's "DCIM" in Ubuntu

Comment: This worked for me. The reason that we got hang deactivating is because the iphone was still connected to USB. unplug then `systemctl restart ...` would avoid this problem.